# Node-RED retreive data from object inside an array

Tags: node-red

this is the returned msg form the SOQL call to Salesforce.
I am trying to just get the word red. what function do i use?
thank you.

```
24/11/2017, 21:34:15node: 752b6f85.12185
msg.payload : Object
object
size: 1
records: array[1]
0: object
pankhurst_dev__color__c: "Red"
```

Comment: Please edit the question to explain a lot more about the flow you are using (may be even a quick screen shot) because the path I've provided in the other answer will get you what you want in a function node.

Answer (score 0):

As you would any other JSON object

```
var foo = msg.payload.records[0].pankhurst_dev__color__c;
```

Comment: thank you for the reply. the reply is still not splitting out the value

Comment: @user2658859 I've edited the answer as I'd only included 1 _ in the last 2 parts of the `pankhurst_dev__color__c` section

Comment: thank you again but still getting the full text in my debug

Comment: 26/11/2017, 00:37:42node: 345d373e.f5f6a8
msg.payload : Object
object
size: 1
records: array[1]
0: object
pankhurst_dev__color__c: "Red"